# How to populate DropdownSearch flutter with local database in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, search, dropdown

I want to populate my `DropdownSearch` with fetching data from local database. Plese help me.

```dart
Future<dynamic> getList() async {
  final db = await getDatabase();
  final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_point_of_Sale");

  List<dynamic> list = 
      res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => PointOfSale.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];
  }
```

```dart
body: Column(
  children: [
    DropdownSearch<String>(
      mode: Mode.MENU,
      items: PointOfSaleDao.db.getList(),
      showSearchBox: true,
      label: "Menu mode",
      hint: "point of sale in menu mode",
      onChanged: (value) {}
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: please helpme am new in flutter... or propose me another solution

Answer (score 0):

As `getList` returns a `Future`, use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to draw the widget for each state the `Future` can be, whether it's still loading or finished fetching the data. The `FutureBuilder` will provide you with an `AsyncSnapshot`. After the `Future` has been resolved, you should be able to access the loaded items by calling `.data` on the `AsyncSnapshot`.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getList(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      snapshot.data    // access the loaded list
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      snapshot.error   // access the error message
    } else {
                       // the future is still resolving
    }
  }
)
```

In case you are using the [dropdown search package](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search), there seems to be a field for that named `asyncItems` on it you might want to look into.